# Separation of Variable PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE :

$$u_{xxxx} + u_{xxyy} + u_{yyyy} = 0.$$

Let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y).$

After the working shown in this wikipedia article under the heading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Example:_mixed_derivatives , we have

$X''(x) = -\lambda_1X(x),\,\, X^{(4)}(x) = \mu_1X(x).$ My question is how did we get  $\mu_1 = \lambda_1^{2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up with
$$0 =\frac{X^{(4)}}{X} + \frac{ X^{(2)}}{X}\frac{Y^{(2)}}{Y} + \frac{Y^{(4)}}{Y},$$
where, as you say, $X$ is a function of $x$ and $Y$ is a function of $y$. Start with the middle term: by the usual argument you need
\begin{align}
X^{(2)} / X &= a, \\
Y^{(2)} / Y &= b
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. That means $X^{(2)} = aX$. Differentiating twice you get $X^{(4)} = aX^{(2)} = a(aX) = a^2 X$, and it follows the term on the left is $a^2$. Do the same thing for the term on the right and you end up with
$$ 0 = a^2 + ab + b^2.$$

Your problem probably has some conditions bounding the solution as $x$ or $y$ or both tend to $\infty$ and that'll limit your choices of $a$ and $b$.